# What to do if I want to remove the effect generated by innerfade

Tags: jquery

What to do if I want to remove the effect generated by innerfade. Means What to do if I want to stop this rotation? My code looks like below.

```
$('#brands').innerfade({
            speed:500,
            timeout: 6000 
        });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/stop/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#brands").stop(true, true);
```

should be enough for your purpose

Comment: I don't know why but $("#brands").stop(true, true); didn't worked for me. as problem was the effect was generated more than one times. as it was written on some id's click button. I tried to use stop but it didn't worked. so as a solution I loaded content of that id each time with the help of ajax. and that solution solved my problem.

Comment: I found another solution to this.

In plugin file at 4 places setTimeout function is used. So assign this to some variable. and when ever u want to stop the rotator just clearTimeout thoes variables. So It's effect will be removed. Means rotator will be stoped.

Comment: .stop() is not working for me. It has no effect on the animation at all.

Answer (score 0):

The .stop() method did not work for me. I've contacted the author of this library, and they told me there is no easy way to cancel the animation.

They also recommended using some other plugins based on InnerFade, but more advanced, such as: [jQuery Cycle](https://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) or Cycle2